# Ionic4 build apk Service GET Method not working Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Tags: ionic-framework, build, ionic4

- Hi, While using local **ng serve** it's working fine.

**ng serve result** :`[{"id":1010,"industryName":"能源"}]`

**But remote chrome inspect console error:**

```
  ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"
```

> Package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
}
```

**ionic.config.json**

```
"proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/code",
      "proxyUrl": "http://x.x.x.xx.x:8010/code",
      "rejectUnauthorized": false
    }
  ]
```

**index.html**

```
  <base href="." />
```

**config.xml**

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />     //I added both even also same problem
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
```

[image: Remote Debug]

**local Debug Console:**
[image: Local Console Debug]

**Note :**

- Why remote debug url showing localhost/code..... like that can't see
  URL is it right?

Comment: What is the value of your base href tag in index.html?

Comment: It's listed Names of Industry but I can see index.html page tags

Comment: Try to change <base href="./" /> in <base href="." /> in the compiled app just before compiling for android and let me know

Comment: I tried also  still have same issue , please check updated remote debug.